# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds in a class constructor

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Environment {
    //variables
    RoundingStage[][] land;
    int horizontalStreets;
    int verticalStreets;

   public Environment(RoundingStage[][] grid) {
       this.horizontalStreets = grid.length;
       this.verticalStreets = grid[0].length;
       land = new RoundingStage[horizontalStreets][verticalStreets];

       for (int i = 0 ; i <= horizontalStreets ; i++)
           for (int j = 0 ; j <= verticalStreets ; j++)
               land[i][j] = grid[i][j];
    }
   public Environment(Environment env) {
        this.horizontalStreets = env.horizontalStreets;
        this.verticalStreets = env.verticalStreets;
        land = new RoundingStage[horizontalStreets][verticalStreets];

        for (int i = 0 ; i <= horizontalStreets ; i++)
            for (int j=0 ; j <= verticalStreets ; j++)
                land[i][j] = env.land[i][j];
    }
```

Can someone tell me why i am getting ArrayOutOfBound when i use this function, I've tried every combination of +1, -1, i need some help please :D

```
public RoundingStage valueInPosition(int rHor, int rVer) {
    return land[rHor-1][rVer-1];    
    }
```

Comment: Sorry i did not understand. Can you explain better ?

Comment: From 0 to n there are n + 1 elements so you should loop from 0 to n - 1. To be clear, replace all your `<=` with `<` in your loop conditions

Comment: Im still getting OutOfBounds on the valueInPosition line . Its out of bounds : -1

Comment: Obviously... if you call `valueInPosition(0,*)` or `valueInPosition(*,0)` it will throw an exception. These are basic mistakes, just check your logic

Comment: You get ArrayIndexOutOfBounds because you use an array index value that is not within the bounds of the array.  A little debugging will tell you precisely which index value (or perhaps array size) is bad.  The exception stack trace tells you the precise statement where the error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You should actually be getting that out of bound exception in those constructors.  Those nested loops using `i` and `j` as iterators should be looping until `i < horizontalStreets` and `j <verticalStreets`, not `<=` as currently posted.  Java array indices are 0-based.

Comment: Im still getting OutOfBounds on the valueInPosition line . Its out of bounds : -1

Comment: @SirHadez Are you able to validate that the arguments being provided to  the `valueInPosition` method are within the right range?

Comment: @SirHadez The way you have implemented this method it looks like
the arguments rHor and rVer in valueInPosition(int rHor, int rVer) are not zero indexed.So obviously if you pass 0 as any of the values then you will be calling land[-1][anyVal] or land[anyVal][-1] and it will throw that exception

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear on your question, but I'm going to assume you mean, "Why does calling the constructor result in an ArrayOutOfBound exception getting thrown?" If that's not what you meant, let me know.

My guess for the exception is that the termination condition for the for loop is i <= horizontalStreets when it should be i < horizontalStreets, and likewise for vertical.

because since array indices start at zero, trying to reference array[array.length()] will try to get an entry that's one after the end of the array, resulting in an exception.